# CPU and fan speed at 100% [Solved in the comments]

Tags: settings, release-hera, macbook, cpu, processes

Hi everyone here's my problem ;( [image: My PC] [image: CPU] [image: Activities]

It happens basically every time, as soon as I turn on my PC the CPU goes directly to 100% and the fan speed reaches the max (6200 rpm), I tried to reduce the fan speed but I'm not a super expert so i didn't find any way to lower it. The CPU even without applications open is always at 100%.

Can you suggest me something to try to solve the issue.

Comment: I myself do not trust gnome-system-monitor. Can you please run `htop` from Terminal and sort the list of processes by CPU usage descending? I am also interested in what is  using so much memory...

Comment: You were completely right system-monitor didn't show some processes that were running. I simply removed them and the fan just stopped.

Thank you Vlad

Comment: Please up-vote the comment as well to give credits to Vlad

Comment: I can't, I have only the flag beside the comment. If Vlad will copy his/her comment into answers, I will more than happy to up-tove it

Comment: Probably it's a kenren issue, you may try to install tlp, see [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/improve-battery-life-on-linux/)